# PDF of X is $f_X(u)=c(1−u^2)$ for some suitable constant c. Find c & PDF of Y where $Y=X^2$.

Tags: probability

> Let $X$ be a continuous random variable defined on the interval $[0,1]$ with density function $f_X(u)=c(1−u^2)$ for some suitable constant $c$.
>   Find: **(a)** the value of $c$, **(b)** **(i)** the expectation and **(ii)** the variance of $X$. Also find **(c)** the density function of the random variable $Y = X^{2}$.

Found $c=\frac{3}{2}$,

$E(X)=\frac{1}{4}$ &

$E(X^2)=\frac{1}{8}$, so:

$Var(X)=\frac{1}{8}-(\frac{1}{4})^2=\frac{1}{16}$

Have I done parts **(a)** & **(b)** correctly? If so how do I go about finding the PDF for Y and if not same question but also where did I go wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Why did you delete your previous question that this one duplicates?

Comment: @Did I assumed there weren't going to be anymore contributions...

Comment: Bad practice, explicitely discouraged...

Comment: @Did Why is that? Not questioning whether you're right or not, I'd just like to know why you consider it bad practice to ask the same question a second time once one realises there aren't going to be anymore contributions.

Comment: @MathWolf Because, as you should now be able to see, the creation of a duplicate question is likely to result in duplication of answers, unless those readers who might answer your question review your posting history before answering.  Do not post duplicate questions:  this site is designed differently than discussion/Q&A forums.  Duplicates **will** be found and deleted.

Comment: MathWolf: What @heropup explained. Let me suggest that you read a page or two of the site about the ways it is supposed to work, if only to avoid future similar faux pas...

Answer (score 0):

Once you have found $c = 3/2$ for part (a), you must also apply that value in your calculation of the expectations; thus you should have obtained $$\operatorname{E}[X] = \frac{3}{8}, \quad \operatorname{E}[X^2] = \frac{1}{5}.$$  As for the last part, observe that the support of $X$ is $[0,1]$, hence the support of $Y = X^2$ is also $[0,1]$, and that on this interval, the mapping $Y = g(X) = X^2$ is monotone; therefore, we can simply use the formula $$f_Y(y) = f_X(g^{-1}(y)) \left|\frac{dg^{-1}}{dy}\right|.$$  Since $g^{-1}(y) = \sqrt{y}$ and $$\frac{dg^{-1}}{dy} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}},$$ all that remains is to perform the substitution, keeping in mind the support of $Y$.

Comment: But I did. I did the integral of $u(1-u^2)$ on (0,1) and then multiplied by $\frac{3}{2}$ to get $E(X)=\frac{3}{2}$. Similarly for $E(X^2)$ I did the integral of $u^2(1-u^2)$ on (0,1) then multiplying by $\frac{3}{2}$ which gives $E(X^2)=\frac{1}{8}$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: @MathWolf How am I supposed to know where your calculation went wrong, when you have not shown me what you did, consequently I cannot **see** what you did?

Comment: What I meant was: Is the method I used correct and if so, the problem must be in my calculations. But I've since found the mistakes I made and resolved them so no worries. Thanks for the solutions.